# javascript string evaluation from php variable that contains mathematical expression (but is actually a date)

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following javascript function.  The function actually populates a jquery date-picker but for this question, I removed that code since it wasn't relevent.

```
function PrintDateToConsole() {
    var testDate;

    <?php
        $test_date = date("Y-m-d", time());
        printf("testDate=$test_date;\n");
    ?>

    console.log(test_date);
}
```

The result that gets printed in the console when I run this code is 1978 (today's date 2014-6-30 = 1978).

Why does the date string get evaluated as a mathematical expression and how can I prevent it?

Note:  I'm fairly certain this is a javascript issue and not a php issue since when I view source on the page I see:

```
function PrintDateToConsole() {
    var testDate;
    testDate=2014-06-30;
    console.log(test_date);
}
```

Comment: You're suffering from the PHP/JS equivalent of an sql injection attack: You are outputting text from one context into another without taking into account how that text will be seen by the receiving context.

Comment: If you want to output PHP values to JS, wrap them with json_encode. You will produce valid and expected literal values for JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
printf("testDate=$test_date;\n");
```

With:

```
printf("testDate='$test_date';\n");
```

The date isn't being passed as a string in JavaScript. Instead, you literally place a number of numbers with substration operators in your JS.
The modification will pass it as a String, properly:

```
testDate='2014-06-30';
```

Comment: bah.  yes, yes, 1000x yes.  I re-read the post after posting (as I always do) and it was obvious to me as well.  I went and tested it and by the time I got back, you had already answered but I have to wait 15mins to accept your answer.

Comment: If you insist on using a _function_, instead of a _language construct_, I'd recommend you use it as intended: `printf('var testDate = %s;', json_encode($test_date));`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, this **is** a computation :

```
testDate=2014-06-30;
```

To get it as a date, you could use

```
printf("testDate=new Date('$test_date');\n");
```

But as you start from the timestamp, there's no point in doing first a formatting and then a parsing. You should simply do

```
printf("testDate=new Date(".time().");\n");
```

This would have the added benefit to avoid the bugs due to the difference of time zone between your server and the user's browser.